# PHP contact form doesn't work

Tags: php, forms, contacts

i've been a couple hours trying to solve this but i can't, the problem is that send the message but it doesn't redirect with header

This is action.php file

```
<?php

$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$correo=$_POST['correo'];
$telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
$consulta=$_POST['consulta'];

$destino="nochetangotours@gmail.com";

$asunto='Reserva Contacto';

$mensaje='Nombre: '.$nombre."\r\n";
$mensaje='Correo: '.$correo."\r\n";
$mensaje='Telefono: '.$telefono."\r\n";
$mensaje='Consulta: '.$consulta."\r\n";


$remitente="From: $nombre <$correo>";


mail($destino, $asunto, $mensaje, $remitente);

header('Location:index.php');

?>`
```

This is  index.php file. Maybe there is something wrong in here, i cant see the mistake

```
<form id="formulario1" name="formulario1" action="enviar.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td class="nombre_form"> </td>
<td><input class="campo_form1"  type="text" name="nombre"id="nombre"placeholder="Nombre*" required/>  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="nombre_form"></td>
<td><input class="campo_form"   type="email" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Email*" required/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="nombre_form"></td>
<td><input class="campo_form"   type="text" name="telefono"  id="telefono"    placeholder="Telefono"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="nombre_form"></td>
<td><textarea class="campo_mensaje"  name="consulta" rows="8" id="consulta" placeholder="Mensaje*" required></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input class="campo_enviar" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

Now im trying that but it doesn't work neither
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<?php
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$correo=$_POST['correo'];
$telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
$consulta=$_POST['consulta'];
$destino="nochetangotours@gmail.com";
$asunto='Reserva Contacto';
$mensaje='Nombre: '.$nombre."\r\n";
$mensaje='Correo: '.$correo."\r\n";
$mensaje='Telefono: '.$telefono."\r\n";
$mensaje='Consulta: '.$consulta."\r\n";
$remitente="From: $nombre <$correo>";
mail($destino, $asunto, $mensaje, $remitente);
header('Location:index.php');
?>
<form id="formulario1" name="formulario1" action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td class="nombre_form"> </td>
<td><input class="campo_form1"  type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"placeholder="Nombre*" required/>  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="nombre_form"></td>
<td><input class="campo_form"  type="email" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Email*" required/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="nombre_form"></td>
<td><input class="campo_form"   type="text" name="telefono"  id="telefono"    placeholder="Telefono"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="nombre_form"></td>
<td><textarea class="campo_mensaje"  name="consulta" rows="8" id="consulta" placeholder="Mensaje*" required></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input class="campo_enviar" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

Comment: is your mail() not sending or redirction not working? what is issue

Comment: i put the html code now, is sending the mail but the redirection is not working, and when i press submit, it shows a empty white page and it says nochetangotours.com.ar/enviar.php

Comment: action="enviar.php" means you have mail code in that file?

Comment: nothing, still the same, i cant find the mistake, i rewrited the code like 10 times

Comment: there is any other way to redirect?

Comment: let me explain you have a php page where is your html code then on enviar.php you have php code and want to redirect redireccion.php after mail?

Comment: yes you can use echo '<script> window.location.href="redireccion.php";<script>';

Comment: it doesn't work neither with the echo '<script> window.location.href="redireccion.php";<script>';

Comment: mail send successfully? then what happening after mail

Comment: it show me the same blank page and in the direction page it says the same

Comment: what is your url in browser

Comment: yes, mail send ok, but then it show me a blank page, and it says nochetangotour.com.ar/enviar.php

Comment: have you any code to redireccion.php which will redirect again to this

Comment: your code is working perfectly let me post in answer what i try and try with my code it's working? all code in same file

Comment: now is working!!! thank you, still the redirect doesn't work i dont know why, i try to put another page instead of index but it doesn;t redirect, thank you very much though!!

Comment: this is the warning that it gives me 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\tour\index.php:202) in C:\xampp\htdocs\tour\index.php on line 219

Comment: you can search for this error you can find many solution for this

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST[something]))
    {
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $correo=$_POST['correo'];
    $telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
    $consulta=$_POST['consulta'];

    $destino="nochetangotours@gmail.com";

    $asunto='Reserva Contacto';
    $mensaje = '';
    $mensaje .='Nombre: '.$nombre."\r\n";
    $mensaje .='Correo: '.$correo."\r\n";
    $mensaje .='Telefono: '.$telefono."\r\n";
    $mensaje .='Consulta: '.$consulta."\r\n";


    $remitente="From: $nombre <$correo>";


    mail($destino, $asunto, $mensaje, $remitente);

     header('Location:redireccion.php');
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting at starting of the page through `header'

then how will your code will work?

so put your header after end of the code

```
<?php


$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$correo=$_POST['correo'];
$telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
$consulta=$_POST['consulta'];

$destino="nochetangotours@gmail.com";

$asunto='Reserva Contacto';

$mensaje='Nombre: '.$nombre."\r\n";
$mensaje='Correo: '.$correo."\r\n";
$mensaje='Telefono: '.$telefono."\r\n";
$mensaje='Consulta: '.$consulta."\r\n";


$remitente="From: $nombre <$correo>";


mail($destino, $asunto, $mensaje, $remitente);

header('Location:redireccion.php');
exit; 

?>
```